# Comparison size_t variable with -1 (maximum size value) in c++ code

Tags: c++, comparison, warnings, unsigned-integer, size-t

I'm refactoring a library and trying to get rid of many gcc warnings. The big part of these warning are about signed / unsigned comparison and are related to the usage of `size_t`. The library works on 64 bit Linux systems.

A programmer used -1 as the special value similar to `std::string::npos`.
There are many places in the library where code looks like this:

```
class AnnotationBase
{
    public:
        size_t m_offset = -1;
        size_t m_length = -1;

}

...

AnnotationBase foo(const std::string& text, const AnnotationBase& annot)
{
    AnnotationBase newAnnot;

    // do some job with annotations and text
    ...

    if(newAnnot.m_offset == -1)
    {
        // do some other job
        ...
    }

    return newAnnot;
}
```

The problem lies in the warning that gcc generates on the line `if(newAnnot.m_offset == -1)` because of a signed / unsigned comparison:

```
"warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]"
```

What is the proper way to compare `size_t` variable in C++ with the maximum value (-1) without warning? Doing this like `if(newAnnot.m_offset == std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max())` is very inconvenient due to complexity and length of this expression.

Is it a good way to use C-style defined value `SIZE_MAX` or it is better to create own constant like `namesapce libling { const NONE = std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max(); }` (Creating new constant leads to many similar constants in different libraries and namespaces like `libling::NONE`, `libother::UNKNOWN`, `liblongnamesapcename::NOTHING`)?

Comment: I would certainly use a named constant, e.g. `if (newAnnot.m_offset == NoneOffset) ... `, which can then be declared as `const size_t NoneOffset = -1;`, which should solve the problem. Using your definition of `NONE` would also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do what `std::string` does and define a `static const size_t AnnotationBase::npos = -1`. Then use that in comparisons as a convention. I wouldn't consider one constant per library a problem, but if you want to avoid that, you can use `std::string::npos` directly (that makes the code more rigid though).

Answer (score 1):

or you can use [this single header](https://github.com/burner/sweet.hpp/blob/master/compare.hpp) library and write

```
if(sweet::equal(newAnnot.m_offset, -1))
```

as pointed out this is always false as size_t can't store a -1. But the comparison will not create any warnings as it handles different types correctly and safely. Additionally, there is

sweet::(less|lessEqual|notEqual|greater|greaterEqual)

Answer (score 0):

`-1` is of type `int`. You need to convert it to `std::size_t` or `unsigned int` via a `static_cast` before you compare it.

Comment: Yes, it is. But comparing size_t variable in the way: `if(newAnnot.m_offset == std::static_cast<size_t>(-1))` is very inconvenient too.

Comment: I agree it is, but you have few options when you start from -1.

Answer (score 0):

Those data should be `ssize_t` instead if -1 is a legal value.
Casting -1 to `size_t` is just cheating the compiler and impose special meaning to the otherwise proper value, although very large, for `size_t`.

If you insist to use the highest value to mean "invalid", use `SIZE_MAX` instead of -1.

Comment: Well, it is an interesting way to deal with the problem, and I think it could be an option in this case. However, it is said that ssize_t is an extension, it is not included in the standard therefore is not portable in other cases.

Comment: By the way, I think that cheating compiler with -1 cast is certainly not good. About special meaning: std::string::npos imposes special meaning to the biggest value of size_t, so it looks like a legal way.

Comment: std::string::npos is just a static size_t with -1 assigned. There is nothing 'cheating' about assigning/casting -1 to a size_t.

Comment: IMO there are many ways you can lie to a compiler and it builds ugly code that work, one way is tell the compiler a size_t (or any unsigned primitives) has an value of -1.

Use SIZE_MAX instead.