# Why does my program skip the while loop? 2 is bigger than -1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

In the test program, the size of v is 2. Since 2 is bigger than -1, I think the while loop should be entered and "!" should be printed infinetely. However, the while loop is getting skipped. Why is that? I tested the code in VS 2017 and Ideone.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main(){
    std::vector<std::pair<int,float>> v = {{1,2.0},{2,2.0}};
    std::cout << v.size();
    while(v.size() > -1){
        std::cout << "!";
    }
}
```

Comment: When I compiled the code provided, my compiler warned the comparison is always false, and that the int was being converted to unsigned long.  I highly recommend you enable your compiler's warnings to raise the visibility of these kinds of easy-to-do mistakes.

Comment: @Eljay was enabled, but no warnings regarding that

Comment: [c++ illogical >= comparison when dealing with vector.size() most likely due to size_type being unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12152605/995714), [Comparison size_t variable with -1 (maximum size value) in c++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25094159/995714), [Why is (sizeof(int) > -1) false? (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34151309/995714)

Comment: You must not have C4287 warning enabled in particular with your compiler, otherwise you would have seen the warning.

Comment: If it doesn't warn that this is always false, then it should at least warn you of a signed/unsigned mismatch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When comparing unsigned type of `std::vector::size_type` and a signed type of `int`, `int` is converted to `std::vector::size_type`. `-1` turns into a very large unsigned integer, which is greater than the size of the vector. Thus the `while` condition evaluates to `false` and the while body is skipped. If you turn on [compiler warnings](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Wc2IRi), you'll get something like:

```
<source>:6:20: error: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'std::vector<std::pair<int, float> >::size_type' {aka 'long unsigned int'} and 'int' [-Werror=sign-compare]

    6 |     while(v.size() > -1){

      |
```

Comment: Note: Most compilers should warn you (or anyone) of things like this.

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed that the first time. I was more so mentioning it for the benefit of the OP, not you, but you already did mention it and I missed it. So just ignore my comment.